# Spring Scheduling: @Scheduled annotation on a method inside a class annotated with @Controller runs twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduler

Consider the below code snippet:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */* * * ?") // run every hour
    public void runMeHourly() {
        LOGGER.debug("RestController#runMeHourly triggered to run at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Do your hourly work here
    }


}
```

When I deploy this controller in a J2EE web server I see that the method `RestController#runMeHourly()` in triggered twice every hour.

I found a reference to something like this here on [spring docs scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

It says:

> Make sure that you are not initializing multiple instances of the same @Scheduled annotation class at runtime, unless you do want to schedule callbacks to each such instance. Related to this, make sure that you do not use @Configurable on bean classes which are annotated with @Scheduled and registered as regular Spring beans with the container: You would get double initialization otherwise, once through the container and once through the @Configurable aspect, with the consequence of each @Scheduled method being invoked twice.

Is this related? Does this mean I need to Schedule the method `runMeHourly()` from outside the `RestController`?

[Edit 1: Looks like the @Configurable is something else and not contributing to the problem, and I have not used it anywhere. So there must be some other reason that is causing this behaviour]

[Edit 2:

My web.xml:

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.company.module.ModuleContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web.xml>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />

    <import resource="module/module-servlet.xml"/>

</beans>
```

module/module-servlet.xml

```
<beans>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.module"/>

</beans>
```

]

Comment: Can you post your web.xml configuration? I would say that you are instantiating you application context twice. Have you tried the scheduled annotation in a @Component?

Comment: @PauloSantos Added the web.xml and other config files. I did not try @ Component yet. In the process of narrowing down. Will build a test case to reproduce the bug.

Comment: You have configured a contextConfigLocation - this is used by the ContextLoaderListener (which is not present in the web.xml you posted). If you have a ContextLoaderListener then your bean has 2 instances, 1 in the app context and the second in the web context - which will lead to this issue

Comment: @6ton You are right. I removed the `ContextLoaderListener` and the `context-param`. And it initializes the context just once. Perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.company.module.ModuleContextListener` is forcing the `DispatcherServlet` to look for a root application context, and since the root application context is same as `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` its being loaded twice. Once as root context and again under DispatcherServlet with the name `mvc-dispatcher`.

Renaming the root context xml `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `applicationContext.xml` and adding an empty `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` solves the problem.

Thanks to @6ton for pointing this out.